# Best choice between Azure AD, B2B, and B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My website will have three user types. Admins, Teachers, and Students. Admins can create/edit/delete teacher users. Teachers can create/edit/delete student users. I was reading about Graph Api to use for creating/editing/deleting users by other user types, and Azure AD types.

In my understanding, B2C is a good choice, because the users are like customers. Could make me sure about which type should I user?

Also, if I use B2C, what would be the best way to identify the user type while signing in. Is adding a User Attribute as UserType (Int) and reading this attribute while calling Graph Api will be a right way?

Comment: Personally, I think regular Azure AD *might* work better since you can define roles in there, and then add users to roles directly when creating them. With B2C, you would have to add users to roles after they have registered. And literally anyone can login with B2C. It's intended for public apps where you just want users to have some kind of identity, and not have to implement all the stuff yourself. But in cases where you need roles and want to decide who has access, regular AAD may work better.

Comment: @juunas Thank you for your comment. If I create the roles for Teacher and Students. The teachers can add students on my website. For Example, T1 Teacher Wants add S1 Student. Would be possible to sent the T1_ID while adding S1 with Graph Api? am I allowed to send S1:UserRole is Student? because I don't want T1 sees/edits T2's students.

Comment: That's probably data that your app can keep track of in its database. When a teacher adds a student, make the necessary Graph API calls to add them, and mark in your database info about the created user and a reference to the teacher that added them. Now the only issue is that if everyone is a member (not a Guest) in the AAD, they can see all the other members if they visit portal.azure.com. Is it important that they do not see each other?

Comment: @juunas. I was thinking the same way to write them in database. However, I don't want the teachers and students to login in to portal.azure.com. They are my website's regular users.

Comment: Your question is just wrong for StackOverflow. Just because there are many possible solutions.

Comment: @astaykov could you tell me a good solution?

Comment: I agree with @junnas . Azure AD B2C is almost like a feature for test. Any one can sign up and sign in your app. If you want to manage users in your organization, the Azure AD may be better.

Comment: Azure AD. Your use case is just like an organizational chart. Perfect for Active Directory. Plus this will be easy to replicate on-premises if ever required.